# Change Text to Speech voice

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am developing an assistant app for android.

I want to make a reply to an user with a different voice but I do not know how to change the voice while making a reply.

Comment: You set the text to speech voice/language by using `tts.setVoice()` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setVoice(android.speech.tts.Voice)

Comment: setVoice() is currently broken if you are trying to use a voice other than the default for that language. Hopefully Google will fix it